# How to connect Promise.all and Promise.race?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

This is simple example:

```
const promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
const promise2 = 42;
const promise3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

const promise4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 500, 'one');
});

const promise5 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'two');
});

const promise6 = Promise.race([promise4, promise5]).then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3, promise6]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

The last console.log return:

> [ 3, 42, 'foo', undefined ]

Is it possible to treat promise.race like a regular promise?

I would like to receive:

> [ 3, 42, 'foo', 'two']

Comment: Remove `then` function from `promise6` --> `const promise6 = Promise.race([promise4, promise5]);
`

Comment: @Yousaf thanks, it was simple... Please add new answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const promise6 = Promise.race([promise4, promise5]).then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
  return value; // <-- You can add return statement here
});
```

Or you can just remove `.then` of the `Promise.race`.